# How do I test in app purchases in expo go?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-go

Everything I have tried doesn't work in expo go. I need expo go as I don't have a mac.

Comment: You have to run it on a phone. So run `expo start` on the terminal, download the expo go app on your phone, and then scan the bar code. Thats it

Comment: Yes I know, sorry for not being clear but it the IAP packages I have tested don't work in expo go. The App won't start.